# UIBarButtonItem not showing image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I'm having a problem with my navigation bar. The issue is that I'm trying to overwride the LeftBarButtonItem that the NavigationBar has from the super viewController like this:

"Super ViewController"

```
UIImageView *logoApp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
[logoApp setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 55, 30)];
UIBarButtonItem *containingLogoApp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logoApp];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = containingLogoApp;
```

Now I'm trying to overwrite it in a different viewControllerB like this:

```
UIImageView *backImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"back.png"]]; 
[logoApp setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 17, 22)];
UIBarButtonItem *containingBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backImg]; 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = containingBackButton;
```

It's the same code, and it works only the first time the app runs. If I run it a second time, it doesn't show the image assigned in `ViewControllerB` anymore. This happens with every image that I have in my project, it only works the first time I run the app on the simulator, after that first run... it's like nothing happens at all.

How can I overwrite the leftBarButtonItem?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *backButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but same result, nothing happens! i created the "backAction" selector, and it´s not called!!! as i said, it´s like nothing related to the navigationBar happens in ViewControllerB´s ViewDidLoad  :(

Comment: @VaroX Does using self work? `[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Nop, this´ what i have right now: 

UIButton *backButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dynamic_blue_left.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(rightSwipeClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

It's working fine.. may be usefull for you